# You have requested a non-existent service "knp_snappy.pdf"

Tags: symfony, pdf, pdf-generation, sonata

I followed the tutorial on https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle and https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/250/how-to-create-a-pdf-from-html-using-knpsnappybundle-wkhtmltopdf-in-symfony-3.

app/config/config.yml

```
knp_snappy:`enter code here`
pdf:
    enabled: true
    binary: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
    options: []
image:
    enabled: true
    binary: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage
    options: []
```

app/AppKernel

```
new Knp\Bundle\SnappyBundle\KnpSnappyBundle(),
```

MyController

```
use Knp\Bundle\SnappyBundle\Snappy\Response\PdfResponse;

public function pdfAction(string $offerId)
{
    $html = $this->renderView('@App/Offer/offer_pdf.html.twig', array(
        'offerId'  => $offerId
    ));

    return new PdfResponse(
        $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html),
        'file.pdf'
    );
}
```

I try and this:

```
 public function offerToPDFAction(string $offerId)
{

    $snappy = $this->container->get('knp_snappy.pdf');

    $html = '<h1>Hello</h1>';

    $filename = 'myFirstSnappyPDF';

    return new Response(
        $snappy->getOutputFromHtml($html),
        200,
        array(
            'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition'   => 'attachment; filename="'.$filename.'.pdf"'
        )
    );
```

The same problem: 
**You have requested a non-existent service "knp_snappy.pdf".**

Comment: The indention in your config.yml is just a copy/paste Problem? Does php bin/console debug:container show the knp_snappy.pdf service?

Comment: Did you clear your cache ?

Comment: I think this makes your .yml invalid => `enter code here`, try removing it

Comment: I checked with php bin/console debug:container and it appear, and I clear the cache, but without any result. "enter code here" - it appears from stackoverflow, I do not have in code

Comment: That's weird. Just to be sure, your controller extends the symfony FrameworkBundle Controller like "class DefaultController extends Controller"? Can you load any other service like logger or mailer?

Comment: I resolved, I reinstall all with all suggestions from knp-snappy-bundle. Ex:  h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64, ...

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * @Route("/{id}/pdf", name="sandbox_pdf", methods={"GET"})
 */
public function pdfAction(\Knp\Snappy\Pdf $snappy, Product $product): Response
{
    $html = $this->renderView('pdf/index.html.twig', [
        'product' => $product,
    ]);

    $filename = 'product';

    return new Response(
        $snappy->getOutputFromHtml($html),
        200,
        array(
            'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition'   => 'inline; filename="'.$filename.'.pdf"'
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use Knp\Snappy\Pdf;

use Knp\Bundle\SnappyBundle\Snappy\Response\PdfResponse;

/**
 * @Route("/show/pdf/{token}", name="admin_invoice_show_pdf", methods={"GET"})
 */

public function showPdf(Command $command, Pdf $pdf)
{

  $html = $this->renderView('admin/invoice/showPdf.html.twig',array('command' $command));
  return new PdfResponse($pdf->getOutputFromHtml($html), 'invoice.pdf');

}
```